# Issue with display driver on HP Elitebook 830 after upgrading to Xubuntu 20.04.2 LTS from Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: drivers, 20.04, display

After doing the upgrade to Xubuntu 20.04.2 LTS from Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS I've had an issue with my screen going blank at random. I can't see anything interesting in `journalctl` or `dmesg`.

The only way I've found to wake up the screen is to close and open the laptop lid.

I've tried changing the power management settings, but it doesn't help.

I'm starting to suspect that this is an issue with the new display driver not being fully compatible with my computer.

A solution might be to downgrade the display driver to the version used in Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS?

Would be happy for suggestions for a solution for this problem!

Comment: Would suggest sending in a bug report with running 'ubuntu-bug linux' in the terminal and see what the developers can figure out.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Link to bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1918940